# Facebook fan page application

Tags: facebook, fan-page

I am planning to make an application which will be used to create facebook fan page like short stack, faceit, etc. Can anybody please suggest me which language to use for developing this kind of application.

Comment: Use a language you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which programming language you are using for your application?

If you are using PHP, you have to import SDK files to your application from www.github.com

If you have any Java standalone application, you can use the **web services** -> **Facebook**-> **Service**, and call them wherever necessary.

FBML has been deprecated, so it is better to go with Facebook Javascript SDK & Facebook Social Plugins.

Please go through:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/ and http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/

Comment: welcome Rocker...

Happy Sharing!!!